# Не загружается изображение в Base64 string на сервер Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit, base64

Пытаюсь решить эту проблему больше 2х недель, изображение в формате bas64encodeToString не грузится на сервер. Загружаю данные на сервер с помощью Retrofit 2. Если загружать просто текст, никаких проблем. Понимаю что может быть большой вес и не загружаться, но с IOS все загружается без всяких проблем. На сервере лимит - вес картины 5Мб.

Так я перевожу в Base64String:

```
public static void imgToBase64ToString(){
    Global.image.clear();
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Global.path.get(0));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Global.image.add("data:image/jpeg;base64," + encodedImage);
    Global.path.clear();
}
```

Post запрос:

```
@POST("event")
Call<CreateEvent1> addEvent(@Header("Authorization") String key, @Header("x-access-token") String token, @Body CreateEvent1 createEvent1);
```

Сама ошибка (Лог):

```
E/Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
        at com.example.golspire.Activity.Events.CreateEventActivity2$1.onFailure(CreateEventActivity2.java:135)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onFailure$1$retrofit2-DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:96)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:144)
        at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
        at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:358)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:230)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readHeaderLine(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:242)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:213)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.java:115)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:94)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:43)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:172)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Сервер ваш? Можете сравнить запросы с андроида и ios? Или в приложениях залогировать и посмотреть какие запросы они отсылают.

Comment: @woesss к сожалению сервер не мой, При попытке загрузки изображения выдаёт TimeoutSocket

Comment: Опубликуйте полный текст (лог) ошибки - это больше похоже на проблему соединения, а не контента.

Comment: @woesss E/Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout

Comment: @woesss Лог тоже добавил

Comment: Скорее всего файл большой и не успевает отправиться до срабатывания разрыва соединения. Попробуйте в OkHttpClient задать WRITE таймаут

Comment: @ЮрийСПб на англ. stackoverflow нашел ответ о том что такие файлы нужно отправлять в Multipart. Не могу разобраться как, как я могу отделить image от остального Body? Или как это правильно реализовать? Сам image в формате List<String>

Comment: Там ничего сложного, однако я более чем уверен, что дело в дефолтном таймауте OkHttpClient  с помощью которого вы создаёте Retrofit. Попробуйте поменять на что-то большое (например 5 минут). Если не поможет - попробую найти работающий код с Multipart

Comment: @ЮрийСПб попробовал сделать по вашему, поставил на 5 минут все равно в конце вывело TimeSocketOut

Comment: А у вас есть рабочий пример отправки запроса? Например в Postman?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да есть вы именно JSON имеете ввиду(В Postman-e)?

Comment: Лучше всего иметь всю информацию - путь запроса, тип, параметры, заголовки, тело.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб щас попробовал добавить @Headers("Accept: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), вывело такую ошибку -> request entity too large код 413